# Jquery dialog should only open once per user

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I use jquery ui modal dialog on a front page and I'd like to show it only one per user. This is my code:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      show: 'slide',
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });


  </script>



<div id="dialog-message" title="Attention">
  <p>Sample text here!</p>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Define 'user'? Once per session, once per page visit, once per IP, once per login credentials?

Comment: sorry i am not specifying it well, once per page visit @gpgekko

Comment: The modal setup code only fires once, on page load, so it only opens once. So that would mean its already doing what you want it to do.

Comment: I mean, i want it to load or appear only once, and when the user visit the page again, the dialog box should not appear.

Comment: Just like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18265236/3068292, but i don't know how to combine the code to my code.

Comment: You need to look into [Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) Padawan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use [`cookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) (like mentioned before) or the [`localStorage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) (depending on which browsers you have to support).

**A way with cookies:**

```
$(function() {
    if( document.cookie.indexOf( "runOnce" ) < 0 ) {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            show: 'slide',
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    document.cookie = "runOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**A way with localStorage:**

```
$(function() {
    if( ! localStorage.getItem( "runOnce" ) ) {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            show: 'slide',
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    localStorage.setItem( "runOnce", true );
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @gpgekko, I tried your first suggestion about the cookies and it work like a charm! I would prefer using cookies because the localStorage has some compatibility issue with other browser. Thumbs up men!

Comment: ,@gpgekko, the above way with cookie works with chrome but I recently notice that it wouldn't work on Mozilla and IE. How should it worked with different browsers?

Comment: My bad, the code above really works with different browsers, I tried it on a different computers. Maybe it's my cache on my browsers. Thanks a lot @gpgekko.

Comment: Using the code for localStorage, when the user loads the same page again, the dialog box doesn't pop up as required. However, its text is already in the body of the page since I am entering it inside a div with same id as the dialog box. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @R.S.K How do you mean? In the DOM or literally visible on the page?

Comment: @gpgekko it is literally visible on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if a user has visited specific page or not. You can keep the status in session variable or cookie. Based on value you can display dialog box.

example using cookie:
include jquery cookie in your html file i.e. https://code.google.com/p/cookies/downloads/list

following code will do your task

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(function() {
        if ($.cookie('page_visited') != 'yes')
        {
            $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
              modal: true,
              resizable: false,
              show: 'slide',
              buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
              }
            });
            $.cookie('page_visited','yes')
        }
});
});
```

You can set cookie expiration period as third parameter `$.cookie('page_visited','yes', expiration_date)`

Comment: I don't know how, can you help me? I'm new to these things.

Comment: Thank you for responding, appreciate it much!

Comment: Hi, the code above doesn't seem to work, I tried uploading the js file with this path:                                                                              <script src="/template/popup_message_cookie/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/template/popup_message_cookie/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>